# Please do anyone know how to use the privacy value on the Facebook graph API because I tried this privacy={"value":"EVERYONE"} but it didn't work

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.8

When ever I use the Facebook graph API to create a post on my Facebook page the post ends up with the privacy set to only me but I want the post to be public I read the privacy docs but I could not really see any solution there when ever I try using different privacy value the API keeps returning an invalid privacy value error.

I tried different privacy value
But I still got nothing but the error

I would love if you guys can help me with a valid privacy value or how it works

Comment: Please clarify what _"use the Facebook graph API to create a post on my Facebook page"_ actually means. Posting onto user profiles via API is not even possible any more, and when you make a post on a page _as_ the page, there is no "privacy" value (but there is `targeting` to limit the audience.)

Comment: I meant using the Facebook graph API to publish to my Facebook page's feed, but when the post is published other users can't see the post.

Comment: Then your app is likely still in dev mode. You will have to take it live, before any people without a role in it, will be able to see any content that was created via it.

Comment: Ok let me try that thanks